# Add event into the event calendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

How do I add an event into another event?

## example

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  events: [
    {
      start: new Date(),
      end: new Date(),

      events: [ {}, {} ] // ??? 
    }  
  ]
});
```

see [screenshot](http://www.fileer.com/cfs/files/files/7nGcYHQzi77ekwZme/i8YcxMGsqSekuSGwL7S4y9AXaZfmSuDTGCzpWBuyGsqcvWnFRs.png?store=files)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible without heavy custom modifications. Very much beyond the scope of an SO question.

The closest you can get easily is to use background events as "parent" events and regular events as child events. Something like the following:

```js
var sourceEvents = [
    {
        id: 1,
        start: moment(),
        end: moment().add(6,'h'),
        childEvents: [{
            start: moment().add(1,'h'),
            end: moment().add(2,'h'),
        }, {
            start: moment().add(3,'h'),
            end: moment().add(5,'h'),
        }],
    }
];

$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
    defaultView: "agendaWeek",
    events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
        var events = [];
        sourceEvents.forEach(function(event){
            event.rendering = "background";
            events.push(event);
            event.childEvents.forEach(function(childEvent){
                // you could do some checks to make sure they are in bounds
                // you could also do some color coding here
                childEvent.parentId = event.id;
                events.push(childEvent);
            });
        });
        callback(events);
    },
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/sxxrs1xj/)